# Rotate NxM Matrix Efficiently when Represented as a One Dimensional Vector of Objects (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra

So far, the only way that I have figured out to rotate an NxM (N not necessarily equal to M) matrix clockwise (when it is represented as a one-dimensional vector with height and width variables stored separately) is as follows:

```
struct matrix
{
  vector<int> data;
  int height;
  int width;

  void rotate_90()
  {
    vector<int> newdata(height*width);
    for(int index = 0; index < height*width; index++)
    {
      int x = index % width;
      int y = index/width; // integer division
      int nextindex = (x+1)*height - 1 - y;
      newdata[nextindex] = data[index];
    }
    data = newdata;
    int temp = height;
    height = width;
    width = temp;
  }
};
```

While this method does work, I'm convinced that there is a far more efficient way (specifically in terms of saving time; space is NOT  a concern).  Having to create a whole new vector and then overwrite the old one with the new one just doesn't sit well with me.  Is there a more efficient solution to this?

Remember, what I have provided above is just for illustration.  The `data` vector in my actual code uses objects instead of ints; using ints was just to make it easier to test.  Hence, a linear algebra library like Eigen is not going to help here.

Comment: If you can find a way to transpose the matrix in place, you can rotate the matrix in place too. You can split the rotate function into two steps -- transpose first and then reverse each row. I spent a few minutes trying to come up with an algorithm to transpose the matrix in place but I couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: the most efficient way to rotate it is to not rotate it ;). If possible you can use an index transformation instead to access the elements as if they were rotated (wrapped in a `rotated_view` eg)

Comment: "Hence, a linear algebra library like Eigen is not going to help here."  I dont know Eigen, but I would expect that eigens matrices can hold any type of objects

Comment: @RSahu that'd be two swaps per cell vs two moves per cell in the original method. Hardly an imorovement.

Comment: Such matrix rotations are permutations that decompose into cycles of sizes 1, 2 and 4.

Comment: @n.m., Valid point. I don't have a feel for how expensive that would be in comparision to constructing and destructing a second vector.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rotate-matrix-elements/

Answer (score 6):

If possible I would try to avoid copying the data completely and only transform the indices when accessing elements:

```
struct matrix {
  vector<int> data;
  int height;
  int width;

  int& at(int x,int y) { return data(x + y*width); }

  struct rotated_view {
    matrix& base;
    rotated_matrix_view(matrix& base) : base(base) {}
    int& at(int x,int y) { return base.at(y,base.height-x-1); }
  }

  rotated_view rotated() { return rotated_view(*this); }
};
```

Note that depending on your access pattern this can have rather poor performance. On the other hand, accessing elements in the original matrix column-wise is almost as inefficient as accessing them row-wise via the `rotated_matrix_view`. If you do care about performance (of course you do, otherwise why would you use C++ ;) I would suggest you to try both, index transformation and actual rotation, to see what is better.

Comment: I think, that this is an elegant solution, if you don't use the transpose of the matrix very often. The usage of this construct will be not cache efficient (since the elements are not continuous in memory) and thus slow. If you just use it once this does not hold, because you don't pay for the calculation of the transpose.

Comment: @schorsch312 a valid concern indeed, I guess I would try both and measure ;)